# Tile shown with line on a device

Tags: ios5, uiimage, uicolor

I use a tile for view background:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
```

In simulator everything is fine, but on real device there is something like line which I want to avoid.[image]

Comment: Answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630870/ios-5-1-with-xcode-4-3-1-uicolor-colorwithpatternimage-strange-behavior-only