# Bottom margin appears within backgroundView (UIImageView) of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios5, uitableview, uiimageview

I designed a custom tableview (based on jQuery Mobile's design) for a native iPhone app. The tableview was sliced into several images (headers, rows etc.) usable as background images within a `UITableView`. I use this image in a `UIImageView` that becomes the `backgroundView` of my custom `UITableViewCell`. Somehow a bottom margin appear on some devices.

To make things easy I don't use iOS's tableview headers. Everything in the tableview is a tableview cell, including the (fake) headers. The height of each cell matches the height of the background image. All views are setup programmatically, so there are no hidden things in a XIB file that could cause the problem.

I use a `UITableView` with style `UITableViewStylePlain`. To prevent regular separators being shown, I use this code in my tableview controller's `viewDidLoad` method:

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

In the `init` method of my custom (subclassed) tableview cells, I apply the background image like this:

```
UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Word.png"];
self.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:backgroundImage];
```

This works perfectly in the iOS Simulator (both iOS 5.0 and 5.1) and on my iPhone and iPad (both iOS 6). However, on the iPhone (iOS 5.1.1) from my client the background image is 2px less high than the tableview cell. Due to this there's a horizontal line visible.

[image: Problem (thumb)]

*click for full image*

To make debugging easier, I added a background color to the cells and their background views in the `layoutSubviews` method like this:

```
self.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
```

For the regular cells I used orange and yellow, and for the header cells I used blue and green. If you look at the image you see that the height of the background view equals the height of the cell. This is confirmed by logging the `frame` and `bounds` of both views.

I have no idea what is going wrong here. All UITableViewCells are exactly the same size as there background image. All images have Retina `@2x` variants that are exactly two times bigger.

Hopefully someone knows what is going wrong here. If you need me to try something, please post a comment and I will. Furthermore I will try to find some other devices with iOS 5.1.1 installed to see what happens there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick google search for:

UIImageView one pixel

returns a previous Stackoverflow discussion that suggests

Set "Compress PNG Files" to "No" in Build Settings

might fix this exact problem: [iOS 5.1 with Xcode 4.3.1: [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:] strange behavior only on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630870/ios-5-1-with-xcode-4-3-1-uicolor-colorwithpatternimage-strange-behavior-only)

Comment: This was the solution. Thank you very much! (Weird thing by the way: disabling compression made the app 40KB smaller. That's one bad compression algorithm.)